# iOS Video Creation Size

Tags: ios, performance, avfoundation, video-capture

I am working on an app which is running some processing on the iOS AV Foundation video stream, and then generating a video using the processed output.

I'm noticing that if I make the output frames of the video too large, the processing time to render the video frames is too large, and my app gets choppy.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for a method I can use to determine at run-time what the largest video size I can create without affecting (drastically) the framerate of the video? This way, if the app is running on an iPhone 5, it should be able to create higher-resolution videos than if it's running on an iPhone 4.

One thought that I had was that before the recording starts, I could try and render a few frames at different resolutions behind the scenes, and time how long the render takes, and use the largest one is takes less than X, but if there's a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Another option would just be to experiment off-line with what gives me good performance on different devices, and hard-code the video resolution per device type, but I'd rather avoid that.

Thanks in advance!